# Connect Sharepoint calenders to outlook, can we modify the sharepoint calender from outlook

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-calendar, outlook

I have a sub-site inside a sharepoint on-premises 2013 team site, and i have enabled the "Offline Synchronization for External Lists" site feature. now from the sharepoint calendar >> I click on "Connect to outlook" , as follow:-

and i got the calendar inside my out look, as follow:-

**but the issue is that i am unable to modify the sharepoint calendar from my outlook, as when  hover over a date inside outlook, i did not get the "+ ADD" link**. also when i did the connect >> i got this dialog which mentioned that my permission will be Read on the calendar (so is this related to my issue that i can not modify the sharepoint calendar from my outlook):-

Comment: are you login your PC and SharePoint with the same windows ID? Are you able to add event if browse to the subsite directly?

Answer (score 0):

to be able to edit in a sharepoint entity your permissions need to be at least contribute. Even a visitor with read rights can read a calendar by connecting as you did but he will not be able to add entries. Check your permissions on the calendar on the original site.

Comment: i have full control on the subsite and on the calendar!!

Comment: have you checked that the calendar itself does not have separate permissions?

Comment: yes i have full permission on the calender..

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you are signed in with the same Office 365 account in Outlook as well? You can also try removing the calendar list and reconnecting it to Outlook.

Comment: yes i am login to the same account + try this on multiple sites and calendar lists and got the same results...